# Are all conditional checks constant Big O?

Tags: big-o

If a function has a O(N) complexity and it is called in an if statement is it still O(1)?

For example:

```
  f(x);
   if (f2(x))
     f3(x);
```

where f(x) is O(N) f2(x) is O(N) and f3(x) is O(Nlog2N).

So would the overall complexity of this fragment be O(Nlog2N) in the worst case where the conditional is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is the worst case scenario.
In one case it is o(n) and other case o(N lg n).

So since we re interested in worst case we say it's latter.

Answer (score 1):

**Big O returns the upper bound (worst case scenario) for time complexity or space of an algorithm.**

> Conditional statements are O(1).

`if (f2(x))` can be written as

```
boolean b = f2(x);
if(b){...}
```

So, the conditional in the above, has O(1), while evaluation of f2(x) above it is O(N).
So the collection will have O(N) complexity.

---

You would take the worst case, of the conditional evaluating to true and then compute it.
**O(Nlog2N)** would be the overall complexity for the block in your question.

**[(Rules)](http://instantkick.blogspot.com/2012/08/what-why-of-big-o-notation.html)**

Comment: And the conditional is just O(1) or O(N)?

Comment: Write it out as the equivalent
`bool cond = f2(x);
if(cond){...}
`

Comment: Overall complexity of the if statement would then be `O(1) + O(N)` which is `O(N)`.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O is an upper bound, so the fragment `f1(); if(f2()) f3();` is `O(f1 + f2 + f3)`. Without knowing anything else, that would be the best possible outcome (since you would have to assume worst-case behaviour).

But, if can *prove* that `f2` is false (e.g. because you've reached the end of a data structure in your analysis), you can cut it down to `O(f1 + f2)`. This is sometimes necessary, e.g. when analyzing the base case of a recursive algorithm.